# Pyspark: Check duplicates over multiple columns with percentage

Tags: pyspark

I would like to check for duplicates or similarities across several columns.

At the end there should be a percentage value indicating the percentage of similarity.

Starting point:

-several tables of plants with customer data: (name, street, city, postal code, country)

All tables are to be compared with each other so that a matrix is created at the end.

Each individual column is to be compared but also a percentage similarity / probability value is to be output.

Has anyone ever done something like this, unfortunately I can't find any approaches when googling.

just google but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare individual columns for duplicates or similarities, you can use formulas in Excel such as `IF`, `COUNTIF`, or `EXACT12`. These formulas can help you compare two columns row by row and return a result indicating whether the values are the same or different12.

To calculate the percentage of similarity between two columns, you could use methods such as the Jaccard Index3 or create a custom function4. The Jaccard Index, for example, involves counting the number of shared members between two sets, counting the total number of members in both sets, dividing the number of shared members by the total number of members, and then multiplying by 100 to get a percentage3.

To compare tables and create a matrix, you can use matrix diagrams5 or create a matrix in Excel6. Matrix diagrams can help you visualize and evaluate complex relationships between data sets5. In Excel, you can use the `SmartArt` feature to create a matrix6.

To compare all tables with each other, you might consider using a programming language like Python or R, which can handle larger datasets and more complex operations. You could write a script to iterate over each table and each column within those tables, perform your comparison, and then store the results in a new matrix.